# Mobile website Issue

Tags: jquery, css, html, jquery-mobile

I have an issue with my `mobile website` where it seems that when you `swipe from left to right` or `right to left` the screen moves showing a gray background beneath it.
Is this something that can be fixed by locking the div down or is it just something to deal with on mobile sites.
 I see that twitters mobile site does the same thing when scrolling up and down, it will drag the viewing area down enough to see the gray background.
  I attached an image to show exactly what I see when dragging right to left.
[image]

NOTE: adding youtube link here:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?client=mv-google&hl=en&gl=US&v=MMPyZ51eO6E&feature=youtube_gdata_player&nomobile=1

Comment: would it be possible for us to see this in action?

Comment: sure, ill post a link to youtube

Comment: youtube won't do in this case. would I be able to see the page where this is occurring?

Comment: sure let me see if I can add a page where you dont need a log in and password

Comment: @darshanags here you go:

Comment: www.happps.com/geishatemplate.php

Answer (score 0):

You have a jQuery UI overlay class ***ui-overlay-c*** typically used for popups applied to your body. Remove this class and you should be good. Also, the HTML in your example link looks strange. i.e: I open http://www.happps.com/geishatemplate.php in my desktop browser and then > view source (ctrl+u) and I cannot see a  or a .

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to go out on a limb and say that, as the behavior you refer to occurs outside of the browsers veiwport, this is dictated by the IOS (I have an iPhone 5 and the effect you have demonstrated occurs when viewing **any** website).

Bottomline - I don't believe this can be done (for a web app..).

Although it is worth noting that this behavior is not identical in chrome for ios (the grey area is a different colour, and instead appears below the address bar).

Answer (score 0):

Add this meta tag inside your html head section.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```